# Draw 21 cards from a standard deck, what are the odds of 6 or more being Q or higher

Tags: probability

Given a standard 52 deck of cards with [12/52 being an Ace, King, or Queen], if you draw 21, what are the odds that 6 (or more) of the 21 cards are either (A,K,Q)?

How do you go about calculating that and how could I do the same for exactly 6, or 5+, 5 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, we want to use the hypergeometric distribution to find the probability of a given number of successes when drawing from without replacement from a finite pool with a given number of success objects in the inital population. The PMF is given by

$$
\text{Pr}(X = k) = \frac{{K\choose k}{{N -K}\choose{n-k}}}{N\choose n}
$$
where $N$ is the population size, $K$ is the number of successes in the population, $n$ is the number of draws, and $k$ is the number of observed successes.

So your answer is given by evaluating the above for $N = 52$, $K = 12$, and $n = 21$. Then, you want to sum the answers for all $k$ such that $12 \geq k \geq 6$. You can obviously choose different $k$ values to get the answers to your other questions.

The formula looks non-trivial but intuitive; ask if you want to see how to derive this formula.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. 

I was able to get getting exactly 6 as .19359 and greater than or = 6 at .3276

Comment: Question, I used a hypergeometric calculator and filled in the numbers. N=52, K=12, n=21, k = 6 to get the above.
 When I tested with k=12 so all possible being selected I get 0%. Why would it say it is not possible to hit all 12?

Comment: It's not exactly 0, but about $8\times10^{-8}$, which maybe the calculator is rounding to 0?

Comment: Yeah that is it. Significant digit error. At n = 25 it calculated .00001 which I guess is the lowest visible in the calculator.

Answer (score 2):

Use the hypergeometric distribution, which is analagous to the binomial distribution but the draws are *without replacement*.

- success is defined by being (A, K, Q)
- the number of draws $n$ is 21
- the population size $N$ is 52
- there are $K=12$ objects with the success criteria

If $X$ is distributed $\text{Hypergeometric}(N,K,n)$, then

- the probability that you get $k$ successes, is given by its PDF evaluated at $k$ on the Wikipedia page.
- the probability you get less or equal to $k$ successes is given by the CDF evaluated at $k$.
- if you want the probability you get $k+1$ or more successes, you can use $1-\text{CDF}$ evaluated at $k$.